# Angular 7 same routing with different parameters

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular-ui-router

I want to reload the component when the params of the routing changed. I have list on the sidebar and I also want to highlighting the list selected on the sidebar.

Sidebar.html

```
  1)List1
  2)List 2
  3)List 3
```

On clicking on the 1st option(List1) for the first time.It is routing to the component(testapi) mentioned in Sidebar component ( this._router.navigate(['/example/testapi',value])). From the second click onwards it is not routing to (testapi component). The  getSomeValue(value:String) is also called for the second time but not routing to (testapi component).

with the help of adding the below in Sidebar.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
   this._router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function() {
     return false;
    };
   }
```

I am able to route with different parameters but the problem is the lists are getting refreshed. So every time I clicked a value from the lists the list value will be refreshed. I want to highlight the list value which I have clicked  and list values should be constant(No refresh should be there after clicking)

Sidebar.ts Here How can I also highlight the selected route with color

```
     getSomeValue(value:String){

      this._router.navigate(['/example/testapi',value]);
     }
```

example-routings.ts

```
      {
      path: 'testapi/:id',

   }
```

https://localhost:4200/example/testapi/123

https://localhost:4200/example/testapi/456   //It is not routing and reloading the component

Answer (score 0):

You can use Router, subscribe to the observable inside constructor.

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
   this.router.events.subscribe((data) => {
     //code goes here
   });
 }
```

Comment: Could you please add as sample code..I didnt  get how to retrived the params and re rout

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

`constructor(private _router: Router)`

```
getSomeValue(value:String){

  this._router.navigate(
        [],
        {
          relativeTo: this._route,
          queryParams: { value: value },
          queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
        });
}
```

In case you need to fetch the value from params, do this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getStates();
    this._route.queryParams.subscribe(
      (params: Params) => {
        if (params.hasOwnProperty('value')) {
           console.log(params['value'])
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please share a Stackbiltz

Comment: I have update my question .. Please go through the question. If still the question is not clear, i will Stackbiltz

Comment: Went through it. this would be difficult to fix it without aw orking example